# Assigning specific values to multiple variable in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to query the WikiData database using their SPARQL endpoint. Here I want to assign specific values to certain variables independent from each other. I know that the VALUES keyword can be used for this, however, is there a way of doing this for multiple variables without having to specify each possible combination? For example, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT ?relation1 ?item1?
     WHERE {wd:Q31 ?relation1 ?item1 .}
```

I would like to specify the values for both ?relation1 and ?item1 without having to go over each possible combination.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer:
Yes, you can use multiple `VALUES` statements.
This can be written like this:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  VALUES ?person {wd:Q35332 wd:Q23844} #Brad Pitt and Geroge Clooney
  VALUES ?property {wdt:P27 wdt:P19} #Country of nationality and place of birth
  ?person ?property ?o ;
          rdfs:label ?personLabel .

  ?o rdfs:label ?oLabel .

  FILTER(LANG(?personLabel) = 'en' && LANG(?oLabel) = 'en')
  }
```

You will then see these results:
[image]

This [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) will contain more information.

Comment: the TE does **not** want to provide all combinations, that was the main concern in the question as far as I understand ... maybe I'm wrong, if not it should be just `VALUES ?person {wd:Q35332 wd:Q23844}
  VALUES ?property {wdt:P27 wdt:P19}` which will generate all 4 combinations

Comment: Oh I see, I think you might have a point after re-reading. I'll leave the answer as is for now and see what he says, and I'll then edit my answer if need be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Indeed, my point was that I did not want to specify all the different combinations since this list is rather exhaustive. However, the other answer did fix the issue. I did try using a double VALUE statement before but placed it outside of the WHERE brackets, this works with one VALUES statement but gives an error with two or more. Including it inside of the brackets fixed the issue. Thanks again for the responses!